# How do Matrix Shards work and where can I find them?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

On Tython I found a [datacron](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42072/what-can-i-get-from-datacrons-and-where-can-i-find-them) containing a Blue Matrix Shard.  I was told that I could combine them in some sort of combiner on Coruscant.  Which leads to a couple important questions:

- How do they work? I.e., what can I make and how many do I need?
- What attributes do the different colors give?
- Can I get them anywhere else besides datacrons?
- Where are they all? I don't want to miss one.

(I think this info is best in one question/answer, but let me know if it should be split.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Three shards can be combined using an Assembler to form a Matrix Cube; the cubes are then used in your character's Relics slots. There found on all the planets and only in datacrons.

As far as the number, there are 67 datacrons. However, there are a limited number of shards to be found (3 red, 3 yellow, 3 blue, 2 green--98% sure, again).

Here's a video walkthrough with more details on how to use them:

!

This is the most comprehensive guide I could find on the locations of the datacrons (including those with shards):

http://www.republictrooper.com/datacron-locations/

Comment: Thanks very much, it's been hard to find a complete and accurate guide.

Answer (score 4):

A pretty comprehensive guide on how to get the datacrons themselves with screenshots and a walkthrough for each, broken down by planet:

http://www.swtor-spy.com/datacrons/

Same site has a guide on the assembly as well:

http://www.swtor-spy.com/guides/matrix-cube-guide/1047/

Have only been able to confirm Empire side guides thusfar, but, found them to be very accurate.

Not saying that this site is definitely better, but, I personally found it clearer to follow.

Answer (score 2):

What I found on google and it worked for me:

http://www.cyberneticpunks.com/matrix-cubes-guide-how-to-make-them/

It has info on the blue matrix shard and other shards. There was also a datacron guide in there

Comment: Hi, Alex, and welcome to the site. Would you care to explain (in a sentence or two) why you think that version is better (and perhaps, reiterate what it says)? Generally, we try to avoid simply linking to something else, as it means the answer is lost if the link ever dies.

Comment: I googled it and thats what I found, Ill make a stack exchange account in a bit then.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: text descriptions of teh shard combinations rather than having to fidn the right place in the video is a great start. Porbably would be better to put the info in here though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Tried to make it as easy and comprehensive as I can in the video :)
Hope these help. Check descriptions for details on how to get the coloured shards as well ^_^
How to assemble & Disassemble a Matrix Cube or Relic (Republic)

How to assemble & Disassemble a Matrix Cube or Relic (Empire)

Comment: This answer would be better if you would summarize the important points of the videos right here in the answer.