# Where can I find all the datacrons and what can I get from them?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've found 3 datacrons so far.  Two gave me a stat boost and third gave me a [Blue Matrix Shard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42071/how-do-matrix-shards-work-and-where-can-i-find-them).  Now I have a couple questions:

- Is there anything else I can get from datacrons?
- Where are they all? I don't want to miss one.

Comment: This seems like an overly broad (aka List) question.

Comment: @Powerlord Questions soliciting answers that together form an *itemized list* are discouraged. Questions soliciting one definitive answer are not, whether that answer might contain a finite list. We have tons of questions of the latter type.

Comment: That doesn't make the list any less overly broad.  As far as we know, you continue finding holocrons until the endgame.

Comment: This question is very similar to your one about Matrix Shards, seeing that the shards come from datacrons. My answer there (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42071/how-do-matrix-shards-work-and-where-can-i-find-them) essentially answers this one as well.

Comment: @Alex True, I didn't want to make them both the same question to avoid being too broad, though as Powerlord says I may have failed here.  Fortunately svick's concise answer proves that a list is unnecessary.  I accepted your answer on the other question :)

Comment: @Powerlord: And any future DLC will add new datacrons too.

Comment: Currently, you can get up to +70 for each stat (except Expertise) if all datacrons are collected. Plus any stats from matrix shard combinations.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to make sure you got all the datacrons on a specific planet, look at the Codex entry for that planet and then click on the magnifying glass. It shows your progress on that planet, including how many of the datacrons you have:

[image: Codex entry for Korriban, showing I have found 2 out of three datacrons]

As for the rewards from datacrons, it seems it's only stats boosts and matrix shards, but I can't say that for certain.

Comment: That's excellent, I had no idea that existed.  Do you know if it's just stats and shards that you get?  If you add that info I'll accept this answer.

Comment: I have added some info about it to the answer, but I can't say for sure there isn't any other reward (I collected only few of them so far myself).

Answer (score 10):

**Alderaan datacrons**

- Aim +4   X: 1106, Y: 78
- Presence +3  X: -81, Y: -267
- Willpower +3 X: -2508, Y: -427
- Strength +4  X: 2191, Y: -2020
- Endurance +3 X: 2721, Y: 2496

**Balmorra (Empire) datacrons**

- Strength +2  X: 727, Y: 2033
- Aim +2   X: -1017, Y: 1514
- Willpower +2 X: 191, Y: -346
- Cunning +2   X: 1853, Y: 111
- Green Matrix Shard   X: -505, Y: 1990

**Balmorra (Republic) datacrons**

- Aim +2   X: 191, Y: -346
- Cunning +2   X: -1017, Y: 1514
- Presence +2  X: 730, Y: 2030
- Endurance +3 X: -485, Y: -233
- Willpower +4 X: -779, Y: 2069

**Coruscant datacrons**

- Presence +2  X: 2320, Y: 1055
- Yellow Matrix Shard  X: 905, Y: 4557
- Strength +2  X: -3087, Y: 3030
- Endurance +2 X: -3729, Y: 161
- Cunning +2   X: 1021, Y: 3967

**Dromund Kaas datacrons**

- Strength +2  X: 855, Y: 643
- Presence +2  X: 581, Y: 798
- Cunning +2   X: -1219, Y: 209
- Yellow Matrix Shard  X: -187, Y: 1738
- Endurance +2 X: -793, Y: 1450

**Hutta datacrons**

- Aim +2   X: -96, Y: 861
- Blue Matrix Shard    X: -22, Y: 319
- Presence +2  X: 497, Y: -13

**Korriban datacrons**

- Willpower +2 X: 529, Y: 65
- Endurance +2 X: 150, Y: 78
- Red Matrix Shard X: -55, Y: 379

**Nar Shaddaa datacrons**

- Republic - Aim +3    X: -3362, Y: -3316
- Republic - Presence +3   X: 3338, Y: -3287
- Cunning +3   X: 1958, Y: 3288
- Republic - Strength +3   X: 2156, Y: 3103
- Yellow Matrix Shard  X: 1702, Y: 3084
- Empire - Aim +3  X: -3699, Y: -1692
- Empire - Presence +3 X: 2930, Y: 400
- Empire - Strength +3 X: 2017, Y: 2441

**Ord Mantell datacrons**

- Red Matrix Shard X: 778, Y: 133
- Presence +2  X: -971, Y: 201
- Aim +2   X: -660, Y: -561

**Taris datacrons**

- Strength +2  X: 1187, Y: -571
- Aim +2   X: -1515, Y: -253
- Cunning +2   X: 1047, Y: 454
- Willpower + 2    X: -362, Y: -227
- Green Matrix Shard   X: 1059, Y: 1039

**Tatooine datacrons**

- Republic - Cunning +3    X: 2140, Y: -3671
- Willpower +3 X: 2115, Y: -596
- Aim +3   X: -628, Y: -30
- Blue Matrix Shard    X: -2391, Y: -1381
- Strength +3  X: -2391, Y: -1381
- Empire - Cunning +3  X: 726, Y: 3137

**Tython datacrons**

- Endurance +2 X: -33, Y: -102
- Willpower + 2    X: -648, Y: -72
- Blue Matrix Shard    X: -93, Y: 925

Source: http://www.swtor-spy.com/datacrons/

Comment: Some datacrons are only accessible by starting at a certain point on the map, or riding a vehicle/transport from a certain point. Are these coordinates for the datacrons or the starting points?

Comment: They're the coordinates for the datacrons. However, the source I linked has complete walkthroughs for how to get to them. I think posting here the full walkthroughs for each is probably outside the scope of StackExchange, though if I or someone with edit capability has time, adding the starting coordinates as well might be useful here.

Answer (score 4):

- Datacrons give you permanent stats boosts. +2 Endurance, +1 Willpower, etc. or a matrix shard in one of the four colors
- In fixed positions in the world
- Can only be used once
- Are *not* used up then wait for respawn; they are enabled via quest-based usage so they may always be used the first time you get to them

About every 1 in 3 (or 5 in the larger planets) instead give you a Matrix Shard of one of four colors: red, blue, green, and yellow. These shards can be combined, and depending on the color order and choices, different permanent stat boosts can be created in the capital city of your respective Side. See [How do Matrix Shards work and where can I find them?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/42071/1134) for more info.

See other resources on the 'net for the lists if you want spoilers. The best list I've seen is at [swtor-leveling.guide.net DataCrons, Matrix Crystals, Relics Guide](http://www.swtor-leveling-guide.net/swtor-datacrons-matrix-crystals-relics-guide), but it is based on preview/pre-release locations and I know some have changed already. Also, try [Republic Trooper's Datacron Locations & How To Get Them](http://www.republictrooper.com/datacron-locations/).

My favorite is [Torhead's Codex Datacrons list](http://www.torhead.com/codices/catg/1). Though it might not be the best list format, once you pick a datacron based on its codex entry, then this site has the best comments, screenshots, and videos to help you find that datacron. Especially considering many require travel starting from a certain point, making the final datacron coordinates (which most lists list) fairly useless.

Comment: Actually, it's one per planet that gives you a shard.  So, once you leave starting planets, it's closer to 1 in 5.

Comment: Also, it's one of four colors: red, blue, green, and yellow.

Answer (score 0):

Of what I've experienced, datacrons can be found around the world at fixed locations. They give some permanent stat boosts, as I heard.