# Datacron Locations

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find all the datacrons and what can I get from them?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42072/where-can-i-find-all-the-datacrons-and-what-can-i-get-from-them)

To englobe all "Where are the datacrons on *blank* planet?" questions, I'm here to ask: Is there a reliable source to find all datacrons of every planet? (like maps or something)

Comment: I think generally questions that ask for links to external sites are discouraged, because there's no guarantee the site will stick around.

Comment: @MatthewRead You do have a point. But the question here is to englobe all questions that will ask for specific planets.

Comment: @Sterno Good thing you copy pasted all locations here. But yeah, I do see the point. We can't rely on external sites to be there forever.

Comment: I've copied my answer to that other question, because I agree, it sounds like a duplicate (though it wasn't answered as thoroughly there)

Comment: @Fredy31 While the other question mentions Tython in the background information, the question itself on the other thread doesn't mention a planet.

Comment: My question isn't limited to a specific planet either.  I don't see how this adds anything, especially given that Sterno posted his answer on mine now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Alderaan datacrons**

- Aim +4   X: 1106, Y: 78
- Presence +3  X: -81, Y: -267
- Willpower +3 X: -2508, Y: -427
- Strength +4  X: 2191, Y: -2020
- Endurance +3 X: 2721, Y: 2496

**Balmorra (Empire) datacrons**

- Strength +2  X: 727, Y: 2033
- Aim +2   X: -1017, Y: 1514
- Willpower +2 X: 191, Y: -346
- Cunning +2   X: 1853, Y: 111
- Green Matrix Shard   X: -505, Y: 1990

**Balmorra (Republic) datacrons**

- Aim +2   X: 191, Y: -346
- Cunning +2   X: -1017, Y: 1514
- Presence +2  X: 730, Y: 2030
- Endurance +3 X: -485, Y: -233
- Willpower +4 X: -779, Y: 2069

**Coruscant datacrons**

- Presence +2  X: 2320, Y: 1055
- Yellow Matrix Shard  X: 905, Y: 4557
- Strength +2  X: -3087, Y: 3030
- Endurance +2 X: -3729, Y: 161
- Cunning +2   X: 1021, Y: 3967

**Dromund Kaas datacrons**

- Strength +2  X: 855, Y: 643
- Presence +2  X: 581, Y: 798
- Cunning +2   X: -1219, Y: 209
- Yellow Matrix Shard  X: -187, Y: 1738
- Endurance +2 X: -793, Y: 1450

**Hutta datacrons**

- Aim +2   X: -96, Y: 861
- Blue Matrix Shard    X: -22, Y: 319
- Presence +2  X: 497, Y: -13

**Korriban datacrons**

- Willpower +2 X: 529, Y: 65
- Endurance +2 X: 150, Y: 78
- Red Matrix Shard X: -55, Y: 379

**Nar Shaddaa datacrons**

- Republic - Aim +3    X: -3362, Y: -3316
- Republic - Presence +3   X: 3338, Y: -3287
- Cunning +3   X: 1958, Y: 3288
- Republic - Strength +3   X: 2156, Y: 3103
- Yellow Matrix Shard  X: 1702, Y: 3084
- Empire - Aim +3  X: -3699, Y: -1692
- Empire - Presence +3 X: 2930, Y: 400
- Empire - Strength +3 X: 2017, Y: 2441

**Ord Mantell datacrons**

- Red Matrix Shard X: 778, Y: 133
- Presence +2  X: -971, Y: 201
- Aim +2   X: -660, Y: -561

**Taris datacrons**

- Strength +2  X: 1187, Y: -571
- Aim +2   X: -1515, Y: -253
- Cunning +2   X: 1047, Y: 454
- Willpower + 2    X: -362, Y: -227
- Green Matrix Shard   X: 1059, Y: 1039

**Tatooine datacrons**

- Republic - Cunning +3    X: 2140, Y: -3671
- Willpower +3 X: 2115, Y: -596
- Aim +3   X: -628, Y: -30
- Blue Matrix Shard    X: -2391, Y: -1381
- Strength +3  X: -2391, Y: -1381
- Empire - Cunning +3  X: 726, Y: 3137

**Tython datacrons**

- Endurance +2 X: -33, Y: -102
- Willpower + 2    X: -648, Y: -72
- Blue Matrix Shard    X: -93, Y: 925

Source: http://www.swtor-spy.com/datacrons/