# Where can I get level 50+ relics that don't require Light/Dark V?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've been leveling my Imperial Agent as Light the whole game, and hit Light V shortly before finishing Corellia. After I finished the Act 3 story I went to Section X on Belsavis and got HK-51 as a companion. I'd like to increase my affection with him while questing on Makeb, but apparently most Light choices make him lose about affection while Dark choices tend to gain about 100 affection. I'm willing to lose Light V to get affection with him, but I'd like to have gear in my relic slots too.

What level 50+ relics are available that don't require you to be as Light/Dark as possible, and where can I acquire them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now outdated and I won't be maintaining it, but is a good historical guide that may have some relevance for those not yet at the current level cap.

---

I'm going to rank all the unaligned relics in the game (best to worst) with how they can be obtained:

1. Revanite (198)

   Drops from Malaphar the Savage in the Temple of Sacrifice operation on Hard Mode.  Cannot be crafted.
2. Resurrected (192)

   Drops from Malaphar the Savage in the Temple of Sacrifice operation on Story Mode.
3. Dread Master (186)

   Drops from Bestia in the Dread Palace operation on Nightmare Mode
4. Ruusan (186, 178, 168)

   Rating 168 schematic available from the Artifice trainer at skill level 500; 178 and 186 versions learned via Reverse Engineering.  **This is probably the lowest tier you want to consider at the moment.**
5. Dark Reaver (174)

   Obtained via Ranked PvP comms (1300 plus the corresponding Exhumed to trade in).  Cannot be crafted.
6. Dread Forged (180)

   Drops from Tyrans in the Dread Palace operation on Hard Mode.
7. Exhumed (168)

   Obtained via Warzone comms (700).  Cannot be crafted.
8. Kell Dragon (174)

   Drops from the Dread Guard in Terror From Beyond on Nightmare Mode.  Cannot be crafted.
9. Underworld (168)

   Drops from the Dread Guard in Terror From Beyond on Hard Mode.
10. Arkanian (162)

    Drops from Calphayus in Dread Palace on Story Mode, the Dread Guard in Terror from Beyond on Story Mode, is a reward for completing the Ops portion of the Oricon storyline, and buyable from the Basic Gear Vendor for 150 Basic comms.
11. Dread Guard (150)

    Drops from Explosive Conflict in Hard and Nightmare Modes and possibly from Eternity Vault or Karagga's Palace, and buyable from the Classic Gear Vendor for 150 Classic comms.
12. Campaign (146)

    Drops from Taral V, Directive 7, and other 50 Hard Mode flashpoints; also drops from the Fabricator Droid in Karagga's Palace on Story Mode and possibly from Eternity Vault or Explosive Conflict.
13. Rakata (140)

    Craftable and usable only by Artificers; schematic available from the trainer at skill level 400.
14. Matrix Cube

    You can assemble these by finding Matrix Shards from Datacrons; [see this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/42071/6066) for more detail.  (This could arguably be slightly higher up the list.)
15. Antiviral Kit

    These come in MK-3, MK-2, and MK-1 flavors usable at levels 45, 35, and 25.  They come from the Rakghoul Resurgence event vendors and are sold from a vendor in the GSI area in the Upper Promenade on Nar Shaddaa while the event is not active.

Answer (score 1):

There are a [lot of relics](http://www.torhead.com/items/catg/2/subcatg/4/slot/49/level/50-55) that do not require level 5 alignment. Many are crafted, so talk to your favorite high-level crafter for those. The rest are mostly available from  running operations.

If you complete the bulk of the Oricon quest series and get to the Dread Palace Courtyard to complete [The Bastion of Fear](http://www.torhead.com/mission/3fUfqj7/ops-the-bastion-of-fear)/[Descent Into the Dark Fortress](http://www.torhead.com/mission/auhC48N/ops-descent-into-the-dark-fortress) quest, you receive one end game relic.

You can get your other [relic drops from operations](http://dulfy.net/2013/04/08/swtor-patch-2-0-operation-loot-tables/), or buy relics with commendations (at the vendors in the Supplies section in the fleet) received from those same operations (if you don't get the drops).

You only have to run story mode (SM) to get enough commendations for the relics, though running hard modes (HM) may help you get there faster assuming you can complete HM runs.

All of the relics from operations do not have alignment requirements.

Comment: You probably should add which commendations you need for the relics you can buy with commendations